# shell command not executing the same from php

Tags: php, wordpress

I am executing a shell command from php using the following:

```
if($dig!=""){
            $command = escapeshellcmd('python3 '. dirname(__file__). '/create_pdf.py digital '.$inv);
   }else{
            $command = escapeshellcmd('python3 '. dirname(__file__). '/create_pdf.py hmml'.$inv);
}
```

This is what is found in create_pdf.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import glob
from fpdf import FPDF
from PIL import Image
import time
import sys
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader


imagetype =  sys.argv[1:][0]

pdf_id = sys.argv[1:][1]


#path containing images - to change to mnt
if imagetype == 'digital':
    root = '/mnt/../Digital/'
    rootPDF = '/home/../public_html/wp-content/uploads/Scans/Digital/'
else:
    root = '/mnt/../VHMML/'
    rootPDF = '/home/../public_html/wp-content/uploads/Scans/VHMML/'

for i in os.listdir(root):
    if  pdf_id in i:
        files = i

imageList = sorted(glob.glob(root+files+'/*.jpg')+sorted(glob.glob(root+files+'/*.JPG')))



pdf = glob.glob(root+"*/"+"*.pdf")


name = root.split(" ")[0]
#path where pdfs are to be stored
namePath = rootPDF+pdf_id+".pdf"

noImages = len(imageList)
factorL = 0.25
factorP = 0.5
im_list = []
start = time.time()

with open('debug.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write(imagetype)
    f.write(pdf_id)
    f.write(str(noImages))
```

Somehow the debug file is written when I run the python script from command line but not from php. Any idea why please? The php code is found in the functions.php of wordpress.

The Apache error log is showing:

```
(32)Broken pipe: [client] mod_fcgid: ap_pass_brigade failed in handle_request_ipc function
```

Comment: Make sure you get no errors returned, or if you do get errors returned make sure to share em within your question. Also make sure to check the permissions set on the files.

Comment: you probably forgot a space in your else branch command at the end. In the near of `hmml`